# python load module from built-in

Tags: python, dynamic, module, built-in

I'm using python 3, and i have a module named `"http" (mypackage.http)`, and i have another module called foo, i want to load the built-in `http module` (not my `mypackage.http` module)

I can use

```
imp.find_module('http', sys.path[1:])
```

for get the built-in `__ init__.py importlib path`

Example:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/__ init__.py`

**But the use of imp.find_module()/load_module() are deprecated.**

how can i import this built-in `http module` by another way like `importlib`?

**project example:**

- mypackage

  - _*init _*.py
  - http.py (has related http classes, etc)
  - foo.py (needs to use built-in http and not the mypackage.http)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of code/package layout that has the problem?  With absolute imports (as in Python 3), you shouldn't have this problem unless you attempt to directly execute a file that is in the package.

Comment: why i can't name my module as I want?

Comment: why python not uses a built-in packages import way?
like import builtin.sys
and i will be able to name my module as i want, import mypackage.sys, or import .sys (relative), import sys(relative) etc

Comment: you can but youll need to make it more namespace-y ... but in general you want unique module names as part of good python design.

Comment: Joran Beasley, why this should be my problem? why python uses "http", i'm want to use the "http" name too, why python has been reserved these module names? why they not use another built-in module import way? like import builtin.http instead of import http (this can be relative to package or for the builtin)

Comment: @fj123x: What are you doing when you get this error?  Are you running the file `foo.py` as a script?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to run foo.py as a script (because is a script what serves a http server)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
import http
```

In Python 2, this wouldn't have worked if `foo` was in `mypackage`, but relative imports need to be explicit in Python 3.

If you're running the module as a script, you'll need to fix the path somehow. If `mypackage` is findable using the normal import mechanisms, then you can run the module with the `-m` switch:

```
python -m mypackage.foo
```

Otherwise, you may need to check the path and alter it manually, as well as setting `__package__` so relative imports work right.

Comment: so how would he import the relative http thats in the same folder? (I havent had much py3 experience)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: He should use `from . import http`.

Comment: nice +1 in this case, my whole answer is useless

Comment: i want to import a built-in module, not a relative mypackage module (i have a conflict naming my module same as one built-in module)

Comment: @fj123x: This does that.

Comment: i'm trying to import the server module from the http package (import http.server). but this is being recognized as module (ImportError: No module named 'http.server'; http is not a package) (because i have a http.py in the same level package where is the foo.py)